# How to solve the error ImportError: cannot import name 'AsyncWebsocketConsumer'?

Tags: python, django, chat, django-channels

I am using Python 3.6 ,Django 1.11 and chennels=2.
I am following this tutorial and it works fine till tutorial part 2: http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/part_2.html

When i moved to tutorial part 3 and changed ChatConsumer file accordingly: http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/part_3.html

I am facing this issue

> ImportError: cannot import name 'AsyncWebsocketConsumer'

Consumer.py:

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

Error:
[image]
[image]
Any kind of will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you import `WebsocketConsumer`?

Comment: Oh you told working find in tutorial 2.. I didn't see it. What happend when you call `AsyncWebsocketConsuemr` in `python manage.py shell`?

Comment: import channels.layers

channel_layer = channels.layers.get_channel_layer()

from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)('test_channel', {'type': 'hello'})

async_to_sync(channel_layer.receive)('test_channel')

i followed this in shell and it worked fine as mentioned in tutorial part 2

Comment: I mean what happen `from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer` in shell? You can call `AsyncWebsocketConsume` in shell but can't only in consumers.py?

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'AsyncWebsocketConsumer' Same error when called from django shell

Comment: Then there's problem in your `channel` library. Can you check version? `pip freeze | grep channels`

Comment: channels version was 2 as mentioned in the question, updated to channel version 2.1 and it solved this error! Channel version 2 was mentioned in the tutorial so i was using channel==2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to channel version 2.1 and it solved this error!

```
pip install channels==2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

To change your consumer functions to async nature you need to import `AsyncWebsocketConsumer` from `channels.generic.websocket`

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
```

Comment: Can you show your consumers.py and also it will be great if you show the fulltraceback. ..

Comment: This tutorial is written for Channels 2.0, which supports Python 3.5+ and Django 1.11+. this is mentioned in the tutorial, i thought django 1.11 is also supported.

Comment: One think more django 2 url.py is different from django 1.11, in Django 1.11 url are used as 
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')

and in Django 2 url are as:
path('admin/', admin.site.urls)

in tutorial url is used as url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')

Comment: url not deprecated completely and you can still use url and path as well. I've checked with 1.11 also and it's working. Can you show me your `pip freeze` output ?

Comment: in tutorial Django version 1.11.10 is used as shown in http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/part_1.html

Comment: i updated Django 1.11 to 1.11.10 but facing same error

Comment: Please update your question with `pip freeze` I will take a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170825/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-haroon-ahmed).